# Old TV style switch off animation

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I'm looking for old TV(CRT)-style switch off animation (if you know what I mean) that would run when my application closes. Don't know if there is a specific name for it. I tried Googling with generic terms, but the only results I see are related to iPhone. I know this will take a `<Storyboard>` and some `DoubleAnimation`s, but not much more than that since I'm not a designer.

Has anyone ever created that effect or know the exact name for this effect so as to search it online? Or maybe if someone could share a basic `<Storyboard>` that I'll then refine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean, I think the best way would be to do it would be by animating a scale transform that is set as the windows render transform. You could trigger this on the Closing event.

Your window would look like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ClosingStoryboard" Storyboard.TargetName="windowScale">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" From="1" To="0.0005" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" BeginTime="0:0:0.3"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform x:Name="windowScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="265" CenterY="400"/>
</Window.RenderTransform>
```

CentreX and CentreY will need to be set you half your window width and height.

Trigger it from code behind like so

```
var sb = this.Resources["ClosingStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
sb.Begin(this);
```

I've just tested this and it works and looks decent enough, could be improved with easing modes and a bit of fiddling, however you need to have your own window style defined or only your windows content will be animated.

Comment: It looks like `Storyboard.Begin()` is not a blocking call. My window closes before the animation even starts.

Comment: You will have to delay the closing until the animation has played. You can cancel the close by setting e.Cancel = true in the Closing event handler, then when the animation is finished close it

Comment: Yep. I managed that. Now I see something, but I won't call it close enough. Not only that it misses the "feel", it also animates just the client-area (as you have mentioned). Doing it on the Window itself doesn't appear smooth at all. The reason I guess is that the window frame itself is outside the jurisdiction of WPF, right?

Comment: You could create your own window style and that would allow you to animate the containing element as I mentioned in the answer. I doubt anyone is going to do all the work for you (especially as you haven't given an example of what you want), you're going to have to put some effort into the animation yourself if you want to get the "feel" right.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

[TV Turn Off and Blip Out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB-bJWsIG_o&noredirect=1)

Comment: Close but not exact. The versions I have normally seen are brighter and faster to shrink. (This should however be a comment, not an answer).

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment

Comment: Go, get it! :) Thanks for digging.